# Python Selenium Loop Through Table Elements

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a script to automate some data retrieval/entry and need to iterate over an unknown number of entries in a table on a web page.  I created a sample you can see here:

[image]

So far my script logs into this ERP system, navigates to the page in the screenshot, and then waits for the `StandardGrid` to load with this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='StandardGrid']")))
```

The `StandardGrid` is where the links are housed on the web page that I want to iterate over.  It's here's where I get lost.

I've tried several different `find_elements_by_XYZ` but can't figure out for the life of me how to get it to work.  I've tried using `ChroPath` with `Inspect` in the browser to identify every way I could think of to get this to work.

The best I could come up with is in this case, the main table that contains the data I want to iterate over has an `XPath` of `"//table[@class='StandardGrid']"`

Therefore, I tried the following:

```
my_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='StandardGrid']")
for item in my_list:
    print(item)
```

But nothing prints out.

The table header of the column I want to iterate over and click on all the links of has the tag of `<th xpath="1">Operation</th>`

In this screenshot, the first URL has a tag of

```
'<a href="../Modules/Engineering/ProcessRoutings/PartOperationForm.aspx?Do=Update&amp;Part_Operation_Key=8355805&amp;Part_Key=2920988&amp;Part_No=WP112789+Rev%2E%2D&amp;Revision=-&amp;Image=&amp;Operation=Polish" onmouseover="status='Go To Detail Form'; return true;" onmouseout="status='';" style="" xpath="1">
Polish
</a>'
```

With the data I'm using there are hundreds of possible links like the one above, so a proper dynamic solution is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to get links directly:

```
operations = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.StandardGrid a[onmouseover*="Go To Detail Form"]')))

for operations in operations:
    print(operations.text, operations.get_attribute['href'])
```

Comment: Thank you - I changed the code slightly to the following at it worked:
`operations = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until( EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.StandardGrid a[onmouseover*="Go To Detail Form"]')) )

for operation in operations:
    print(operation.text)
    print(operation.get_attribute('href'))`