# How to get value of WebElement

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to loop through table elements on a page of our ERP system.

Based on a question I asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59901360/python-selenium-loop-through-table-elements) I thought this would be a slam dunk - but I cannot figure it out.

Here's the latest code I've tried:

```
approved_suppliers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody[@id='ApprovedSupplierBody']")
for supplier in approved_suppliers:
    print('Supplier',supplier.id)
```

if I substitute `print('Supplier',supplier.id)` with `print('Supplier',supplier.value)` I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'value'
```

In the screenshot example I want the code to print `300 Below`, and when there are multiple suppliers the names of the fields increase by 1.
For example, `pik_Supplier_1`, `pik_Supplier_2`, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element with `id` `ApprovedSupplierBody` is a single element, to get the elements with `id` `pikSupplier` you need to include it in the xpath

```
approved_suppliers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody[@id='ApprovedSupplierBody']//input[starts-with(@id, 'pikSupplier')]")
```

To get the value you need to use `get_attribute` to get the value property

```
supplier.get_attribute('value')
```

You need to do the same with `id`, `supplier.id` will return internal `WebElement`'s `id` property, something like `92505ac9-2c32-447e-b94a-8c7398b53e0e` and not `ApprovedSupplier`.

Comment: just tried `supplier.get_attribute('value')` in my loop's print statement and it returned `None`.
I'm confused on what to select to iterate over.  I've also tried `"//table[@id='ApprovedSupplier']"` but can't seem to find how to grab these elements in a loop.

Comment: @Python_Learner_DK Updated my answer.